# Url PrevPost after migration

Tags: previous-post-link

I make a migration to another server with duplicator and I have a bug with the URL when I call this :

```
 <a href="<?php echo $prev_post->guid ?>"><?php echo $prev_post->post_title ?></a>
```

As result, the URL is old and I want new URL.

Comment: You should be using the permalink not the GUID

Comment: ok it's work with the  Velvet Blues Update URLs thank you Tom !